# Android MySQL PHP JSON error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I want to add data to MySQL for Android, I use PHP service but I get in error `"invalid IP adress"`. Can you help me?

Android code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              masa=e1.getText().toString();
              yemek=e2.getText().toString();
              icecek=e3.getText().toString();
              tatli=e4.getText().toString();
              insert();
          }



       });

    }
    public void insert() {


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("masa",masa));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yemek",yemek));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("icecek",icecek));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tatli",tatli));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/add.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
```

PHP code:

```
    <?php

    $baglan=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $sec=mysql_select_db("bitirme",$baglan);


    $masa=$_REQUEST['masa'];
    $yemek=$_REQUEST['yemek'];
    $icecek=$_REQUEST['icecek'];
    $tatli=$_REQUEST['tatli'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($query=mysql_query("insert into yemekler (masa,yemek,icecek,tatli) VALUES ('$masa','$yemek','$icecek','$tatli')"))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($baglan);

?>
```

Comment: did you changed the ipaddress as per your machine?

Comment: invalid ip adress get error at try cath block.looking source codes please

Comment: @Naufal: please don't recommend that website, the tutorials contain a number of bad security practices that shouldn't be promoted (SQL injection, clear text passwords, deprecated libraries...).

Comment: Try using the ip of the machine where the server code is running.

Comment: i try used all ip4 adrees but i get same error

Comment: Please don't use pasteboards here, as they render questions useless if the third-party site goes down, or the link breaks. Use code formatted in Markdown, as per my edit.

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your PHP code, and you should be using POST, not REQUEST (since it is a write operation). Don't use your MySQL root account for web applications.

Comment: Is you android device connected to the same private network as your server?

Comment: yes android device same private network server

Answer (score 1):

you can use ip address of ur pc instead of mobile ip address.